# Expression Engine 2 Next/Previous Entry Linking with Full Entries List

Tags: expressionengine, pagination

I want to use the Next/Previous Entry Linking technique in EE2:

```
{exp:channel:next_entry}
    <p>Next entry: <a href="{path='site/comments'}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}

{exp:channel:prev_entry}
    <p>Previous entry: <a href="{path='site/comments'}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:prev_entry}
```

When this works, I'm on a single entry `ie. awesome.com/index.php/my-cool-entry`, I can click page through the entries in that channel.

**Is it possible to ALSO display a full list of the entries on this page while I'm looking at one article? I want to be able to show the list of entries as a way to navigate to a particular article.**

Think of it like the way `{pagination_links}` builds links: 
First Page < 1 2 3 > Last Page except instead of numbers I want to display parts of that entry, rather than just a number.

What bothers me is that `{paginate}` generates ugly URLs `ie. awesome.com/index.php/articles/P1`, I'd rather have `awesome.com/index.php/articles/my-cool-entry`. `exp:channel:next_entry/prev_entry` preserves the URL_title!

Is there a plug-in that can handle this kind of thing?

Comment: The reason that pagination can't use URL titles is that usually you're displaying multiple entries per page. What it sounds like you want to do is to list *nearby* entries - i.e., the previous X number of entries and the next X number of entries. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Embedding a template is the way to go.

Create a new template with an `{exp:channel:entries}` loop. Within that you can dump out the  entries you want and display any info you want from them.

One thing to make sure of is to use the `dynamic="no"` parameter within the `{exp:channel:entries}`.  It'll go something like this:

In your article page, embed another template:

```
{embed="article/full_list"}
```

And within the `article/full_list` template use a loop like:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" channel="[YOUR CHANNEL]" LIMIT="10"}
    <a href="{title_permalink}">{title}</a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```